# test if file exists then create it remotely - sync delay

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I need to check locally if a file exists, then generate it remotely via ssh, then check its content locally. So, if I check its existence before generating it remotely, I get syncing delay. Is it possibly to avoid this delay?

**Case1**:

```
outfile=$HOME/testfile.$$.1.txt  # non-existing file
test -f $outfile && echo "exists"  # test the file
ssh $remote_host touch $outfile  # create it remotely 
stat $outfile  # check it locally
```

Not found:

> stat: cannot stat 'testfile.1234.1.txt': No such file or directory

It is needed to wait before it gets visible:

```
echo -n "wait: "
while [[ ! -e $outfile ]]; do
  echo -n "|"
  sleep 1
done
echo " done"
```

> wait: |||||||||||||||||||||||||| done

**Case2 - without 'test' command:**

```
outfile=$HOME/testfile.$$.2.txt  # non-existing file
ssh $remote_host touch $outfile  # create it remotely
stat $outfile  # check it locally
```

it is visible immediately:

```
  File: ‘testfile.1235.2.txt’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1048576 regular empty file
  ...
```

Comment: The key piece of information missing in your question is why you expect file creation over SSH to have a local effect. My assumption is that both machines share a network-based or distributed filesystem. Which most likely works with a concept of distributed clocks or “generations” of some sort, for which it should be possible to wait passively using a filesystem-specific command line utility.

Comment: what is the output of `findmnt -nT $HOME` ?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, you are right - both machines share a network-based filesystem. It is not clear why case1 and case2 give different results and how to force data sync immediately, not waiting for 10+ seconds. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @jhnc `/home <ip>:/storage/rbd/home nfs    rw,noatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=<ip>,mountvers=3,mountport=<port>,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=<ip>`

Comment: if this is a linux client, you can try adding `acdirmin=n` / `acdirmax=n` (for small int n) or `lookupcache=none` or `noac` : https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfs.5.html#DATA_AND_METADATA_COHERENCE

Comment: if your [`stat`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) supports it, you can also try adding `--cached=never`